# LINK2019 keeps going

Tags: hyperlink

Hi I am having the following error in my VS 2010 project and have no clue where is the problem. I have read about it and changing the windows <-> console doesn't work for me and gives me the same error:

1>------ Build started: Project: Draw, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>MSVCRTD.lib(crtexe.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol *main referenced in function _*_tmainCRTStartup
1>C:\Users\Desktop\Draw\Debug\Draw.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: What project type did you create?

Comment: I have tried both windows and console project in Visual Studio 2010 C++, but I get the same error every time.How do you mean by project type?

Comment: Yeah I was wondering if it was console or some other project type. What exactly are you trying to compile? Do you have a "main" in you code?

Comment: 1$ Unistroke in C++ . I am trying to compile the C++ version (by baylor wtz) on the website on Visual Studio 2010: 

http://depts.washington.edu/aimgroup/proj/dollar/                               I see what you mean by not having a main function, saw that reason somewhere while I was searching. I think there is no main function in the code, but since someone else has written it I am not sure how can I fix it without messing with the code. I only want to compile and use the gesture recognition.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to get it working. The code you pointed out is just a collection of classes that you can use in your project.

To use them, you can create a new empty console project, add those files and also add a `main.cpp` file like this one:

```
#include "GeometricRecognizerTypes.h"
#include "GestureTemplate.h"
#include "GeometricRecognizer.h"
#include "SampleGestures.h"
#include "iostream"

using namespace DollarRecognizer;
using namespace std;

void main()
{
   GeometricRecognizer *g = new GeometricRecognizer();
   g->loadTemplates();
   SampleGestures sample;

   RecognitionResult result = g->recognize(sample.getGestureArrow());

   cout << result.name << "\n" << result.score;

   int stop;
   cin >> stop;
}
```

It worked for me, it detects the sample arrow, loaded as a collection of points from `SampleGestures.h`.

Comment: Thanks for that. I did what you said (basically copy and pasted that to a new main.cpp on my console project. I am have these errors now:

Comment: 1>------ Build started: Project: $1 Unisroke, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  GeometricRecognizer.cpp
1>c:\users\desktop\$1 unistroke\$1 unisroke\geometricrecognizer.cpp(345): error C2653: 'main' : is not a class or namespace name
1>c:\users\desktop\$1 unistroke\$1 unisroke\geometricrecognizer.cpp(347): error C2065: 'shouldIgnoreRotation' : undeclared identifier

Comment: 1>c:\users\desktop\$1 unistroke\$1 unisroke\geometricrecognizer.cpp(349): error C2065: 'shouldIgnoreRotation' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\users\desktop\$1 unistroke\$1 unisroke\geometricrecognizer.cpp(351): error C2065: 'angleRange' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\users\desktop\$1 unistroke\$1 unisroke\geometricrecognizer.cpp(355): error C2065: 'angleRange' : undeclared identifier
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: you have to include all those files in the project.

Comment: Ok, so I had all those files previously, but I started a whole new project and added them all again. It doesn't have any error now but how does this work? am I not able to draw the gesture somewhere and the it gets recognized by the program?

Comment: this is a recognition library, not a drawing library. Which means you have to do the drawing in another way (OpenGL maybe), export the points in the format that this library expects (see `SampleGestures.h`) and then call the recognition code.

Comment: You never used the file PathWriter.h did you? what does this file exactly do? is the 'savedPath.txt' which  is being called actually  the file which contains the x,y coordinates of a possible drawn gesture?

Comment: `main` should return `int`, not `void`.